# Selenium WebDriver: Finding the row of a table containing two input values

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working on function that takes two values in a table then verifies the row that contains the two values to verify if a third value exist in that row.

The code below finds the row where the two values are. However, it will not break out of the for loop if rowNo and rowNo2 are equal. I've tried using .equals() but that gives me an error. Any tips?

```
try {
            // Get the row number of passed row Data
            WebElement table = oWebDriver.getWebElement(tableObject);
            List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
            List<WebElement> cols = table.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int colSize = (cols.size()) / (rows.size());
            int rowNo = 0;
            int rowNo2 = 0;
            int colNo = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < cols.size(); i++) {
                WebElement cellData = cols.get(i);
                if (cellData.getText().contains(rowData)||cellData.getText().contains(rowData.toUpperCase())) {
                    int l = i / colSize;
                    rowNo = l + 1;
                    for (int k = 0; k < cols.size(); k++) {
                        WebElement cellData2 = cols.get(k);
                        if (cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2)||cellData2.getText().contains(rowData2.toUpperCase())) {
                            int n = k / colSize;
                            rowNo2 = n + 1;
                        }

                        System.out.println("row No2 = " + rowNo2);
                        System.out.println("row No1 = " + rowNo);
                        if (rowNo == rowNo2) {
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you share your code? What you have done so far?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Added code above